# controlling the size of an image when clicked

Tags: php, html, click, size, anchor

The following php script is used to load an image from the database! when the image is clicked an enlarged image appears but when i give height and width it remains the same large size! I want to reduce the size of the clicked image to 
height=100 and width=100 Though i gave them it did not work

```
 echo'<div class="ienlarger"><a href=../ordering/'.( $row['Image1'] ).' height=100 width=100><img src="../ordering/' .$row['Image1']. '" alt="thumb" class="resize_thumb" /><span>
    <img src="../ordering/' .$row['Image1']. '" alt="large" height=500 width=500 /><br />
    Copy-1</span></a></div>';
```

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the clicked image isn't 100x100 is because **there is no `width` or `height` attributes in the `a` tag**. If you think about it, since `a` tag or anchors can link to all types of documents, including non-image files and non-html files (i.e. it could link to a file download). And in the case of a download, it wouldn't make sense to have a `width` attribute.

I would suggest if you really want this functionality, you could either create an image 500x500 resolution and create a similar one with a 100x100 resolution....

Or if you can't afford that space, you could create a javascript that does that. For example (not sure if it works):

```
<div class="ienlarger"><img src="../ordering/<?php echo $row['Image1'] ?>" alt="thumb" class="resize_thumb" />
<span>
<img id="sizable" src="../ordering/<?php echo $row['Image1'] ?>" alt="large" height=500 width=500 /><br />
Copy-1
</span>
<script>
     document.getElementById("sizeable").onclick = function(evt)
     {
         evt.target.width = 100; 
         evt.target.height = 100;
     };
</script>
</div>
```